# Magento admin panel give Fatal error: Class "Helper_Data" not Found

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute

I have installed one module extension which throws an fatal error Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Clarion_Customerattribute_Helper_Data' not found in .../app/Mage.php on line 547 when i clicked on "Manage Attributes".

Following my ***\app\etc\modules\Clarion_Customerattribute.xml*** file

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Clarion_Customerattribute>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Clarion_Customerattribute>
</modules>
</config>
```

Following my ***\app\code\community\Clarion\Customerattribute\etc\config.xml*** file

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Clarion_Customerattribute>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Clarion_Customerattribute>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <clarion_customerattribute>
            <class>Clarion_Customerattribute_Model</class>
        </clarion_customerattribute>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <clarion_customerattribute>
            <class>Clarion_Customerattribute_Helper</class>
        </clarion_customerattribute>  
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <clarion_customerattribute>
            <class>Clarion_Customerattribute_Block</class>
        </clarion_customerattribute>
    </blocks>
</global>

<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <clarion_customerattribute>
                    <file>clarion_customerattribute.xml</file>
            </clarion_customerattribute>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <clarion_customerattribute>
                <file>clarion_customerattribute.xml</file>
            </clarion_customerattribute>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <clarion_customerattribute after="Mage_Adminhtml">Clarion_Customerattribute_Adminhtml</clarion_customerattribute>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<!-- Clarion_Customerattribute_Adminhtml indicates the path of the admin controller-->
<default>
    <general>
        <validator_data>
            <input_types>
                <text>text</text>
                <textarea>textarea</textarea>
                <date>date</date>
                <boolean>boolean</boolean>
                <multiselect>multiselect</multiselect>
                <select>select</select>
            </input_types>
        </validator_data>
    </general>
</default>
</config>
```

Following my ***\app\code\community\Clarion\Customerattribute\etc\adminhtml.xml*** file

```
<config>
<menu>
    <customer>
        <children>
            <customer_attribute translate="title" module="clarion_customerattribute">
                <title>Manage Attributes</title>
                <sort_order>601</sort_order> 
                <action>adminhtml/customerattribute</action>
            </customer_attribute>
        </children>
    </customer>
</menu>
<!-- Aceess permission for the node admin/customer/customer_attribute-->
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <customer>
                    <children>
                        <customer_attribute translate="title" module="clarion_customerattribute">
                            <title>Manage Attributes</title>
                            <sort_order>601</sort_order> 
                                <children>
                                    <save translate="title">
                                        <title>Save Attribute</title>
                                        <sort_order>0</sort_order> 
                                    </save>
                                    <delete translate="title">
                                        <title>Delete Attribute</title>
                                        <sort_order>0</sort_order> 
                                    </delete>
                                </children>
                        </customer_attribute>
                    </children>
                </customer>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

Here is ***\app\code\community\Clarion\Customerattribute\controllers\Adminhtml\CustomerattributeController.php***

```
class Clarion_Customerattribute_Adminhtml_CustomerattributeController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function _initAction()
    {

         $this->_title($this->__('Customer'))->_title($this->__('Attributes'))->_title($this->__('Manage Attributes'));

         if($this->getRequest()->getParam('popup')) 
         {
            $this->loadLayout('popup');
         } 
         else 
         {
            $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('customer/customer_attribure')
                ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('clarion_customerattribute')->__('Customer'), Mage::helper('clarion_customerattribute')->__('Customer'))
                ->_addBreadcrumb(
                    Mage::helper('clarion_customerattribute')->__('Manage Customer Attributes'),
                        Mage::helper('clarion_customerattribute')->__('Manage Customer Attributes'));
         }
         return $this;
          public function indexAction() 
          {
                $this->_initAction()->renderLayout();
          }
}
```

Here, ***\app\code\community\Clarion\Customerattribute\Helper\Data.php***

```
class Clarion_Customerattribute_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{   
//some code;
}
```

I tried to empty `/var/cach`e folder. but it not work. I also tried to replace **clarion_customerattribute** to **customerattribute** in CustomerattributeController.php file but it not work.

Please help me for solving this problem (Fatal Error)

Comment: please post full module..

Comment: Is your compilation enabled? If yes - please recompile.

Comment: @michael i also tried your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clarion_Customerattribute.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Clarion_Customerattribute>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Clarion_Customerattribute>
</modules>
</config>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Clarion_Customerattribute>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Clarion_Customerattribute>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <clarion_customerattribute>
            <class>Clarion_Customerattribute_Model</class>
        </clarion_customerattribute>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <clarion_customerattribute>
        <class>Clarion_Customerattribute_Helper</class>
      </clarion_customerattribute>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <clarion_customerattribute>
            <class>Clarion_Customerattribute_Block</class>
        </clarion_customerattribute>
    </blocks>
</global>

<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <clarion_customerattribute>
                    <file>clarion_customerattribute.xml</file>
            </clarion_customerattribute>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <clarion_customerattribute>
                <file>clarion_customerattribute.xml</file>
            </clarion_customerattribute>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <clarion_customerattribute after="Mage_Adminhtml">Clarion_Customerattribute_Adminhtml</clarion_customerattribute>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<!-- Clarion_Customerattribute_Adminhtml indicates the path of the admin controller-->
<default>
    <general>
        <validator_data>
            <input_types>
                <text>text</text>
                <textarea>textarea</textarea>
                <date>date</date>
                <boolean>boolean</boolean>
                <multiselect>multiselect</multiselect>
                <select>select</select>
            </input_types>
        </validator_data>
    </general>
</default>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <customer>
        <children>
            <customer_attribute translate="title" module="clarion_customerattribute">
                <title>Manage Attributes</title>
                <sort_order>601</sort_order> 
                <action>adminhtml/customerattribute</action>
            </customer_attribute>
        </children>
    </customer>
</menu>
<!-- Aceess permission for the node admin/customer/customer_attribute-->
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <customer>
                    <children>
                        <customer_attribute translate="title" module="clarion_customerattribute">
                            <title>Manage Attributes</title>
                            <sort_order>601</sort_order> 
                                <children>
                                    <save translate="title">
                                        <title>Save Attribute</title>
                                        <sort_order>0</sort_order> 
                                    </save>
                                    <delete translate="title">
                                        <title>Delete Attribute</title>
                                        <sort_order>0</sort_order> 
                                    </delete>
                                </children>
                        </customer_attribute>
                    </children>
                </customer>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

**Data.php**

```
<?php 
class Clarion_Customerattribute_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{   
//some code;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @quisar sorry its my mistake it already closed in original code.

Comment: i tested it by my self there were two addition i added in that

Comment: @quisar thank you for your response i tried but not working. it still give same error....

Comment: it working on my side it will give you all code..

Comment: its work in your magento but not in my magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: did you replace the code? i check it 1.9.0.1 its working

Comment: i update **Clarion_Customerattribute.xml**, moves all the file from **community** folder to **local**, update your **config.xml** and **adminhtml.xml**.    but not work

Comment: disable the cache and then check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29894/discussion-between-hardik-and-qaisar-satti).